# How can I know which version of WPF I am running?

Tags: wpf, versioning

I have discovered some differences between WPF 3.0 and WPF 3.5.
As a result, I need to know if an assembly was compiled against 3.0 or 3.5.
Is there a API for this?

Answer (score 3):

The version number for the current installed version of Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) is located in the Registry.

To find the version number:

1.

```
  On the Start menu, click Run.
```

2.

```
  In Open, type regedit.exe.
```

3.

```
  Open the following key:
```

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup\Windows Presentation Foundation

The WPF version number is stored in the Version value.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to determine this from the referenced assemblies of your targeted assembly.  Take a look [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies(v=VS.100).aspx) to check out the GetReferenceAssemblies method of the System.Reflection.Assembly class.